# get return value from webmethod using Mootools' ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net, mootools

I'm trying to get a value from VB.NET using Mootool's Ajax. 
But I keep on getting the whole HTML code of Default.aspx instead of the return value from the function I called in Ajax.

This is my script in Default.aspx (using Mootools 1.5)

```
var year = $('<%=ddlYear.ClientID%>').value;
var month = $('<%=ddlMonth.ClientID%>').value;
var week = $('<%=ddlWeek.ClientID%>').value;
var updateChart2 = new Request ({
    method: "post",
    url: "/Default.aspx/updateChart",
    data: {"year":year, "month":month, "week":week}, 
    update: "divChart",
    onFailure: function () {
                  alert('error');
                },
    onSuccess: function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
                  //some code
                }
    });
updateChart2.send();
```

and this is my code in Default.aspx.vb

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function updateChart(ByVal year As String, ByVal month As String, ByVal week As String) As String
    Dim a As String = ""
    'some code to change "a" value
    Return a
End Function
```

Is there something wrong in my code?